# opencv-python нет подсказок

Tags: python-3.x, консоль, opencv

в Pycharm установил opencv-python через терминал, всё встало без ошибок, но вот с подсказками беда. Выглядит это так: [image: подсказки]

но код отрабатывает, как положено: [image: код отработал]
а вот если работаешь в консоли, то там все подсказки есть: [image: подсказки в консоли]
Переустановка Pycharm и питона не помогли, при этом удалял хвосты вручную. На первом скрине у меня видно, что подсказки из cv2, а у людей cv2.cv2 Если написать from cv2 import cv2  ругается

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается копированием файла cv2.pyd из Python310\Lib\site-packages\cv2 в папку Python310\Lib\site-packages
[image: Исправлено]
**Всем добра!**